# On a property of linear transformation and its adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

Here is the item I am proving.

"Let $\sigma$ be a linear transformation on an inner product space $V$. Prove that $\ker \sigma=\ker\sigma^*$ if and only if $\sigma\sigma^*=\sigma^*\sigma$.

I have proven $(\Longleftarrow)$. That is:

Suppose  $\sigma\sigma^*=\sigma^*\sigma$. Let $\alpha\in V$. Then

$0=\sigma(\sigma^*(\alpha))=\sigma^*(\sigma(\alpha))$ which means $\ker \sigma \subseteq \ker \sigma^*$ and $\ker \sigma^* \subseteq \ker \sigma$.

Then I stopped. I am wondering when to use adjoint properties. Or does the star does not necessarily mean adjoint? Any suggestion for the other direction?
Please help me get notified in case relevant properties are needed. Thank you....

Second attempt.
I proved $\ker \sigma=\ker\sigma^*=\ker\sigma\sigma^*=\ker\sigma^*\sigma$ using result here ([Let $V$ an inner product space and $T:V \to V$ a linear transformation. Prove $\operatorname{Ker} (T^*T)=\operatorname{Ker} T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4706872/let-v-an-inner-product-space-and-tv-to-v-a-linear-transformation-prove)).

Comment: Consider $\langle \sigma \sigma^* x, y \rangle = $?

Comment: The “only if” part is false. Every invertible linear transformation $\sigma$ satisfies $\ker \sigma=\ker \sigma^\ast\,(=0)$, but some of them are not normal.